# Unable to locate and open MATLAB after installation in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: matlab

I have installed Matlab R2015a in my ubuntu 17.10 system. ***After its showing installation complete, I am unable to locate MATLAB icon in the application list and hence I am unable to open and activate the program and then use it.

Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Are you able to run `matlab` from a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Determine where you get MATLAB installed (let's call it $MATLAB_ROOT) and try to launch it from terminal as `$MATLAB_ROOT/bin/matlab`. MATLAB icon may have `.xpm` or `.png` extension, you can add it to the desktop launcher.

Comment: I have installed Matlab in the Documents portion after I open Home. There bin is located and inside that matlab is also located. But still I am unable to open it. Please suggest any way

Answer (score 0):

The **default location** of the MATLAB installation is `/usr/local/MATLAB/`. So if you didn't change the default path during installation you should be able to open MATLAB by typing

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab
```

Be aware of adapting the command to the right MATLAB version if you are not running R2015a.

If not yet done during the installation itself you can **create a symbolic link** allowing you to open MATLAB by typing `matlab` from anywhere. This is done by the following two commands

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab matlab
```

To add an **entry to the launcher** and some other features, install the matlab-support package by

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

During the installation you have to confirm the installation path of matlab and could restrict the installation only to certain users (leave empty to not restrict). In addition you could rename the GCC libraries.

After completion, you have to **change the ownership** of the .matlab folder in the home folder to your own user account if you do not want to run Matlab as a super user.

```
sudo chown username -R ~/.matlab
```

[You might also want to have a look at the Ubuntu Community MATLAB page with some more info on troubleshooting.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)